# How to symbolicate a crash that occured in framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, crash-reports

I got this crash log from production:

[image]

This is visible via XCode organizer -> Crashes. The lines in red rectangle are of interest to me but they are not symbolicated. EasyTypeShared is a framework written by me and it is contained in the project. How can I symbolicate that part of crash report? Why is it not symbolicated by default?

Comment: Have you compiled your framework in release or debug mode?

Comment: @Gusman Release - because otherwise XCode will submit debug versions of framework to App Store (did not find a way to setup the main project to use debug framework build for its debug build na release for its release build).

Comment: well, then that's the cause, release builds will not generate debug symbols by default, if you need to symbolicate the result then you can check the "Generate Debug Symbols" option and uncheck "Strip Debug Symbols", in this way you will have a release compilation but with debug symbols.

Comment: @ Gusman Unfortunatelly does not seem to work - On EasyTypeShare framwrok, I set "Generate Debug Symbols" to Yes, "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to No, cleaned the framework and build it again. Closed and reopened Organizer but still cannot see the symbols.

Comment: You need to publish the new package and then get a new crash report which uses the framework with the debug symbols, there's no way to get the symbolication if the crash report comes from a source without debug symbols (at least none I know and I had a similar problem and seeked the same as you and nothing arised).

Comment: Well, I recall something that maybe can help you, but if the addresses of the newly compiled framework changed then you're out of luck, you can use atos to get what's in a concrete address, check this: https://coderwall.com/p/ezdcmg/symbolicating-an-ios-crash-log-without-the-original-dsym-file look at the final option.

Comment: I see - was thining that is what you ment... Unfortunate, but better than nothing. Thank you.You might want to make an answer of it so I can later accept it if it works

Comment: Don't worry, I just like to help. If you can to get it work add the answer yourself, I will upvote it surely.

Comment: @Gusman This is completely wrong! Symbolication will work if the actual symbols (dSYM) package of that framework build is available. You do **NOT** need to add debug symbols to frameworks, symbolication works the same way for binaries and frameworks.

Comment: @Kerni So what you are saying with regard to my question? It should already work (well, it does not) ? Gusman's advice will not help? Do you suggest and specific steps to solve the problem? Thank you

Comment: Those crashes are provide by iTunes Connect, and likely symbolicated on Apples servers. So the most likely problem is that you app build archive doesn't include the symbols of that framework.

Comment: @Gusman Your suggestion did not work. New build was submited with "Generate Debug Symbols" on and "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" off for the framework but the framework symbols. Still crash reports for crashes that occured in the framework after the new release are not symbolicated.

Comment: @Kerni I still do not understand you: You suggest that my app build does not include symbols of the framework but you dismiss Gusman's suggestion that is trying to solve just that - change build settings of the framework so that the framework's build would include those symbols. Can you explain what you ment?

Comment: Symbolication uses a dSYM package that is created when you build your app which results in an app package. Same happens with frameworks where you get a framework package and a dSYM package. If you don't get your dSYM package, check your build settings in the framework project regarding that. Then all those dSYM, framework and app packages should be part of your archive. Those will all be uploaded to iTunes and then Apples servers can symbolicate. If something is not happening in there, create a new question with way more details and what is there and what is not.

Comment: I'm not posting this an an official answer, since a a repo, and not an answer. But with that sad, this is exactly what you are looking for. This finds objects by symbol, and you can specify a build: https://github.com/agentsim/Symbolicator Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Xcode isn't always the best at symbolicating crash reports in the organizer. I recommend using the command line tool (`symbolicatecrash`) to confirm that it isn't an Xcode issue.

As long as you have a local copy of the dSYM you should be good to go, even if it never got uploaded to Apple.

Place the `.dSYM`, `.crash` and `.app` in the same folder then in Terminal cd into the folder and run these commands:

```
# symbolicatecrash requires this value to be set
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

# could instead add this to your bash profile
SYMBOLICATE_FOLDER=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/

# symbolicate asdf.crash into out.crash
$SYMBOLICATE_FOLDER/symbolicatecrash asdf.crash > out.crash
```

Comment: This is a generic answer to symbolicate a crash log from an app. Here the issue is how to symbolicate the crash occurred in an internal framework.

Comment: Wow! it worked like a charm. I was able to symbolicate the crash occured in the framework as well. You need to put the framework.dSYM file under the same folder where the app.dSYM file is available.

Comment: @ParamTrivedi: Can you please tell us where do you find the dSYM file for your release framework ??